# Bootstrap Dropdown: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, npm, popper.js

I am trying to get a dropdown to appear from a navbar; however, I am getting an error.

```js
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')
```

I can confirm I have both **Bootstrap** and **Popper** installed through npmjs.

```js
import { createPopper } from '@popperjs/core';
import bootstrap from 'bootstrap';
```

Both are being imported into a JavaScript file, which is imported as a **module** into my index HTML file.

I have tried adding Popper to the JavaScript file which contains my imports. This did not work. I would need the dropdown to open below my navbar. What is interesting is that adding my navbar to a website, such as StackBlitz, it works perfectly fine. I feel this has something to do with my npm configuration. I have attached my code below.

### Navbar Code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">ABCalc</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Account
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <li><h6 class="dropdown-header">Dropdown header</h6></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

### Javascript Imports:

```js
import { createPopper } from '@popperjs/core';
import bootstrap from 'bootstrap';
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the class `dropdown-menu` to your outer `<ul>` on line 8 of your code snippet, like so:

```html
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">ABCalc</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">

          <!-- next line modified to add dropdown-menu class -->
          <ul class="dropdown-menu navbar-nav">

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Account
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <li><h6 class="dropdown-header">Dropdown header</h6></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: You saved me. Adding ```dropdown-menu``` did the work.